# Get MongoDB document by ID on Java

Tags: java, mongodb, search

I have a set of ID's of documents which I add previously in MongoDB.

Then I try to get Document from ID.

```
String idString = "57f8f50977c8a5b8757f261a";
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put("_id", idString);
DBCursor cursor = table.find(whereQuery);            
if(cursor.hasNext())
{
 System.out.println("FOUND!" + cursor.next());
}
```

I get zero results.

But, if I call another field
It works and return me document.

```
BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
whereQuery.put("datachain", "AA");
DBCursor cursor = table.find(whereQuery);
if(cursor.hasNext())
{
System.out.println("FOUND!" + cursor.next());
}

FOUND!{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57f8f50977c8a5b8757f261b"} , "datachain" : "AA" , "createdDate" : { "$date" : "2016-10-08T13:30:49.588Z"}}
```

What I do wrong? Why I can't find document by ID's?
Thnx!

UPD:
    BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    whereQuery.put("_id", new ObjectId("57f8f50977c8a5b8757f261a"));
    DBCursor cursor = table.find(whereQuery);

Same, no result founded.

Comment: You need to turn your `String` into an [`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the idString as an `ObjectId`.

```
whereQuery.put("_id", new ObjectId(idString));
```